# How save the variable outside an if statement

Tags: java

I have this java code:

```
String e;
if(true){
e = "ee";    
}
if(e == "ee"){
 System.out.println(e);
}
```

How I can "use" the variable e out the first if statement?
I add some stupid conditions (if(true).. etc.) just for try.

I'm SOrry for my bad english :v

Comment: Comparing strings using the `==` operator doesn't do what you think it does. Use `"ee".equals(e)` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is and whether you are getting an error and what is it?

Answer (score 1):

You have saved it, you're just comparing it wrong. Use the `equals` method to compare values. The `== operator` compares referential equality.

Comment: This `equals` and `==` must do the same thing in this case.

Comment: In this case, yes, but with  condition like 'if(true)' I doubt this is the actual code he's running, but just a short representation of what he's doing.

Comment: Good point. IMHO It's not clear what the problem OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

To compare the variable with another string use equals and not ==. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

```
String e;

if(true){
  e = "ee";    
}

if(e.equals("ee")){
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: This will do the same thing in this case.

Comment: "ee".equals(e) (as JonK suggested in the comments) is safer.
As soon as the condition is no longer if ( true), or as soon as mutation testing will be done on this code, it will throw one NullPointerException after the other.

Comment: @Stultuske it is safer, but is it an answer to the problem or more of a comment?

Comment: @PeterLawrey when putting code in answers, isn't it best to make the snippets as good as possible? Anyway, I didn't downvote and only posted it as a comment, since I agree the vital information is in there, doesn't mean the remark can't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be that the compiler doesn't know your variable must be set. There is a number of way to solve this.

Give it a default.

```
String e = null;
```

or make it clear that the alternative branch is impossible

```
if (condition) {
   e = "ee";    
} else {
   throw new AssertionError();
}
```

or give it an alternative value.

```
if (condition) {
   e = "ee";    
} else {
   e = "that was unexpected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String e;

if(true){
  e = "ee";    
}

if("ee".equals(e)){
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Because If e will be null then you will not get nullPointerException, If you will use like above

```
if("ee".equals(e)){ //Some operation }
```